# Change factor labels in psych::fa or psych::fa.diagram

Tags: r, psych

I'm using the `psych` package for factor analysis.  I want to specify the labels of the latent factors, either in the `fa()` object, or when graphing with `fa.diagram()`.

For example, with toy data:

```
require(psych)
n <- 100
choices <- 1:5
df <- data.frame(a=sample(choices, replace=TRUE, size=n), 
                 b=sample(choices, replace=TRUE, size=n), 
                 c=sample(choices, replace=TRUE, size=n), 
                 d=sample(choices, replace=TRUE, size=n))
model <- fa(df, nfactors=2, fm="pa", rotate="promax")

model

Factor Analysis using method =  pa
Call: fa(r = df, nfactors = 2, rotate = "promax", fm = "pa")
Standardized loadings (pattern matrix) based upon correlation matrix
    PA1   PA2   h2   u2 com
a  0.45 -0.49 0.47 0.53 2.0
b  0.22  0.36 0.17 0.83 1.6
c -0.02  0.20 0.04 0.96 1.0
d  0.66  0.07 0.43 0.57 1.0
```

I want to change `PA1` and `PA2` to `FactorA` and `FactorB`, either by changing the `model` object itself, or adjusting the labels in the output of `fa.diagram()`:

[image: fa.diagram]

The [docs for `fa.diagram`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/1.7.8/topics/fa.diagram) have a `labels` argument, but no examples, and the experimentation I've done so far hasn't been fruitful.  Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `str(model)` I found the `$loadings` attribute, which `fa.diagram()` uses to render the diagram.  Modifying `colnames()` of `model$loadings` did the trick.

```
colnames(model$loadings) <- c("FactorA", "FactorB")
fa.diagram(model)
```

[image: fa.diagram]